# Clustering features in ArcGIS JS

Tags: maps, arcgis, polygons

I know there are some solutions for clustering points. I'm working with a feature layer that uses polygons to outline properties. What I'm trying to figure out is if there's anyway to do zoom-based clustering.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by adding 2 layers, one for the clustering and one for the outlines. Then you can set the `minScale` and `maxScale` on each of these layers so that they are only visible when the map scale is between the min/max values.

Example reference for minScale https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#minScale